# How to override onClick on Android Spinner?

Tags: android

A normal android [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) will pop up a list of choices when clicked. I want to override this onClick. When the user clicks the spinner during certain error states, I want to display an error message rather than pop up the list of choices. Currently, all I can do is set a [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html), but its onClick method doesn't let me prevent the list of options from appearing.

Answer (score 5):

Extends from Spinner and override performClick() like this:

```
@Override
public boolean performClick() {
   if(errorOccured) {
       // show validation message
       return true; // the event is handled by ourselves
   }
   else {
       return super.performClick(); // show spinner dialog
   }
}
```

See sources for more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting a [`onTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and in the `onTouch` method display your popup and return `true` to consume the event and stop it from propagating to the view (Spinner in this case).

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   // display your error popup here
   return true;
   }
});
```

This should stop the "drop down list" from appearing.

**Edit:** forgot to mention you could do your error state check in the `onTouch` method as well, so you don't completely disable the spinner.

Comment: The remarks under the edit are what I ended up going with. Minimal intrusion to get some cross fragment control limitation in different states.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a MySpinnerAdapter class, that implements SpinnerAdapter. In your MySpinnerAdapter, take a look at the getDropDownView method. I believe that's where the pop-up view is created. You could check your error state, and decide to return a different view there (allthough it might be in another function -> check the documentation)...

**Anyway, this answer is not a copy-paste one. Just trying to spit some new ideas**

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity
{

    private class MySpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter
    {
        // There are quite a lot of methods you need to implement...

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
                // Check your error states here
                if(<we have some kind of error>)
                    return specialErrorView // you get the idea

                // return the default view with options
                return normalView;
        }
    }
}
```